# DI Service issue in .NET Core passing through controller to repo

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am sharing code with you the problem is that when I access the `_service.UserName`, it is always null. When I debug this code at the time of log in of the user, it has a value, but when I reach the `HomeController`, it is null.

My question is how to pass values to repo in .NET Core - I also register the service.

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ScopService>();
}

public Class LogInController()
{
   public ActionResult LogIn()
   {
     _userService.UserName = Convert.ToString(Userdt.Rows[0]["UserName"]); //values set correctly
     return Redirect to Home Index Page
   }
}

public Class HomeController
{
  HomeRepo repo;
  public ScopService _userService { get;}

  public HomeController(ScopService ser)
  {
    _userService = ser; //_userService found null no value
     this.repo = new HomeRepo(_userService);
  }
}


public class HomeRepo
{
   public ScopService _service { get; }

   public HomeRepo(ScopService service) : base(service) 
   {
        _service = service; //found no value
   }

   public void find()
   {
       string username  =_service.userName;
   }
}

public class _baseRepo
{
     protected readonly ScopService _userService;

     public _baseRepo(ScopService userService)
     {
         _userService = userService;
     }
}
```

.NET Core Singalon Service Controller have null service found

Comment: `ScopService` is registered as Scoped, so it is disposed of between calls.

Answer (score 0):

When service is declared as Scoped, then it will has a new instance on every scope, by default ASP Core creates a new scope on every HTTP-Request.

Try to change

```
services.AddScoped<ScopService>();
```

into :

```
services.AddSingleton<ScopService>();
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Umer Ullah , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?